# How to redirect to home page in kentico after login in site intead Admin/cmsadministration.aspx?

Tags: redirect, authentication, kentico

I'm trying to redirect the users to home page after to log in. I've already added default target URL in the web part also in the template, I tried also by code

```
else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(DefaultTargetUrl))
        {
            redirectUrl = ResolveUrl("~/Compliance.aspx");
        }
```

I also add a new domain alias with a default alias path but nothing is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using ~/admin as the login page, create your own ~/login page, that can be redirected to anywhere. If you use the default ~/admin it result to /CMSPages/logon.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fKentico11%2fAdmin%2fcmsadministration.aspx which return URL is the Admin/cmsadministration.aspx